How do I spatially join coordinates in a matrix (points) to polygons in a large spatial polygons data frame in R?
I am having an issue spatially joining coordinates (points) in a matrix to polygons in a large spatial polygons data frame (df). I need to do a spatial join because I want to take the mean of a column called prob_enrolled which is found in the matrix with points and summarize by the polygons found in the large spatial polygons df.
The matrix (A) looks like below.
     lat  long   survey_age  prob_enrolled
1   -16   24      4           0.0720
2   -14   28      4           0.0620
3   -10   32      5           0.1175

Whereas the large spatial polygon df looks like this (Zambia_districts) with two lists: data and polygons. The polygons list contains the information to join the coordinates by.
Within the polygons list there are 116 polygons representing each district in the country so the [[1]] and [[2]] under Zambia_districts@polygons goes to 116. Within each district, there is ANOTHER list of 1 containing the polygon information such as lappet, area, hole, ringDir, and coords. (It is a lot of nesting sorry about that).
The structure of Zambia_districts looks like this
Zambia_districts
  -> data
        OBJECTID integer[116]
        FEATURE_TY character[116]
        PROVINCE character[116]
        DISTRICT character[116]
        Shape_Area double[116]
        Shape_Length double[116]
        m_0 double[116]
        m_1 double[116]
        ...
        m_59 double[116]
  -> polygons list[116]
     -> [[1]] S4 (sp::Polygons)
       -> Polygons list[1]
         -> [[1]] S4 (sp::Polygon)
            labpt double[2]
            area double[1]
            hole logical[1]
            ringDir integer[1]
            **coords** double[4000 x 2]
         plotOrder integer[1]
         labpt double[2]
         ID character[1]
         area double[1]

So I essentially want the mean of prob_enrolled by polygon (district) and to also plot the map and color code each polygon by prob_enrolled value.
I have tried converting the matrix to a SpatialPointsDF and using over() from the sp library but I am getting an error. This method was a solution I tried from a different question asked on stack overflow.
# Convert matrix A to df
A <- as.data.frame.matrix(A)
# Convert df to SpatialPointsDF
coordinates(A) <- ~ long + lat
# Define projection
proj4string(A) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

a.data <- over(A, Zambia_districts@polygons[,"coords"])

Here is the error I am getting. Am I headed the right direction? I feel like I am stuck because of the data within Zambia_districts.
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'over': incorrect number of dimensions


Hi Zizi, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. However, I do understand  that this can be difficult for new users so I have provided an answer. Nonetheless, please do edit your question, particularly given that sharing images of data is discouraged for these reasons. Thanks

Hi L Tyrone I edited my question and sorry about that!

That is an improvement, but in this case you are expected to provide an actual sample of your data. You can do this using the dput() function. Given that your entire districts data are too large to add to your question, you could  run dput(head(zmb_dist, 1)) and add the result to your question. The advantage of using dput() is that it tells us everything about your data.

Given that you did not provide an example districts dataset, I have downloaded data from here to use in this example. It is the closest data to your screen capture example that I could find (by virtue of the feature count). In future, please ensure that your question is a minimal, reproducible example.
There are a few issues to contend with here:

the sp package was deprecated last year, so it's probably better to switch to the sf package unless you absolutely have to use sp
your sample points are outside the border of Zambia, I have modified your example points in order to return a representative result
This example assumes that the coordinate values and CRS of both your districts data and your points data are WGS84:EPSG4326. If this is not the case, update your question with more details

library(sf)

# Data from https://data.humdata.org/dataset/cod-ab-zmb? and previously unzipped 
# to working directory
# Use this example as a basis to re-read your districts data into your environment 
# as an sf object
zmb_dist <- st_read("Shapefiles/zmb_admbnda_adm2_dmmu_20201124.shp")

# Modified version of your point data as a data.frame()
A <- read.table(text = "       lat   long   survey_age  prob_enrolled
1   -16   24      4           0.0720
2   -14   28      4           0.0620
3   -10   32      5           0.1175", header = TRUE)

# Convert your point df to an sf object (CRS set to match zmb_dist e.g. WGS84/EPSG:4326)
A <- A %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Spatially join zmb_dist to A
A <- st_join(A, zmb_dist)

A[,1:6]
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 6 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 24 ymin: -16 xmax: 32 ymax: -10
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   survey_age prob_enrolled Shape_Leng Shape_Area       ADM2_EN ADM2_PCODE       geometry
# 1          4        0.0720   5.057628  0.9304583       Senanga     ZM9005 POINT (24 -16)
# 2          4        0.0620   5.232826  0.7801793 Kapiri Mposhi     ZM1003 POINT (28 -14)
# 3          5        0.1175   4.762331  0.7915888        Mungwi     ZM6011 POINT (32 -10)


